# form post in asp.net mvc 3 is direct to some other method in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

**view**

```
@model demo.Models.PhoneSell
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddPhonesToSell", "PhonesSell", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div>
    <label>Mobile Brand</label>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.brand, new { @class = "form-control"         ,placeholder="Brand"})
    </div>  
</div> 
 <div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:100px;"     value="Ready to sell"/>
</div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Advertise()
    {
        return View();
    }

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPhonesToSell(demo.Models.PhoneSell model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

when I click on the submit button it should to AddPhonesToSell method but its going to Advertise method.

How can I redirect to AddPhonesToSell method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the name of the controller that AddPhonesToSell() is in?  Also can you show us the <form> element HTML that this is generating?

Comment: PhonesSell..if you have seen my above code...! but i have to use razor engine in my project.